# GridView generates INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have what seemed to be a very simple search box with a button. This posts back to a results page with a grid view. The query works fine, but when I go into the advanced SQL generation options and select "Generate INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements", then checking "Enable Editing" in the GridView tasks, it doesn't work.

I use the search box, the query returns results, I click on the **Edit** button on the row that I want to edit and the page goes blank. This is especially confusing as this is all I have had to do on other pages with gridviews and it has worked without issue.

I've tried to fix this by researching the problem online, but I'm not understanding what to do. I feel like I'm being pointed in the direction if binding the ID column, but I'm not sure, and I'm unfamiliar with binding; the ID column is the key column of the table. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="resultssm.aspx.cs" Inherits="search_shipping_resultssm" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            EnableModelValidation="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemNumber" HeaderText="ItemNumber" SortExpression="ItemNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="Quantity" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RoomName" HeaderText="RoomName" SortExpression="RoomName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkOrderName" HeaderText="WorkOrderName" SortExpression="WorkOrderName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Height" HeaderText="Height" SortExpression="Height" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Width" HeaderText="Width" SortExpression="Width" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Depth" HeaderText="Depth" SortExpression="Depth" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReleaseDate" HeaderText="ReleaseDate" SortExpression="ReleaseDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductionStartDate" HeaderText="ProductionStartDate" SortExpression="ProductionStartDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StageDate" HeaderText="StageDate" SortExpression="StageDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipDate" HeaderText="ShipDate" SortExpression="ShipDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DeliveryDate" HeaderText="DeliveryDate" SortExpression="DeliveryDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="InstallDate" HeaderText="InstallDate" SortExpression="InstallDate" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IQConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductTracking] WHERE ([WorkOrderName] = @WorkOrderName)" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ProductTracking] WHERE [ID] = @ID"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ProductTracking] ([ID], [ItemNumber], [Name], [Quantity], [RoomName], [WorkOrderName], [Height], [Width], [Depth], [ReleaseDate], [ProductionStartDate], [StageDate], [ShipDate], [DeliveryDate], [InstallDate]) VALUES (@ID, @ItemNumber, @Name, @Quantity, @RoomName, @WorkOrderName, @Height, @Width, @Depth, @ReleaseDate, @ProductionStartDate, @StageDate, @ShipDate, @DeliveryDate, @InstallDate)"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [ProductTracking] SET [ItemNumber] = @ItemNumber, [Name] = @Name, [Quantity] = @Quantity, [RoomName] = @RoomName, [WorkOrderName] = @WorkOrderName, [Height] = @Height, [Width] = @Width, [Depth] = @Depth, [ReleaseDate] = @ReleaseDate, [ProductionStartDate] = @ProductionStartDate, [StageDate] = @StageDate, [ShipDate] = @ShipDate, [DeliveryDate] = @DeliveryDate, [InstallDate] = @InstallDate WHERE [ID] = @ID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ItemNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RoomName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="WorkOrderName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Height" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Width" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Depth" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="ReleaseDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="ProductionStartDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="StageDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="ShipDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="DeliveryDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="InstallDate" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:FormParameter 
                    FormField="SMSearchBox" 
                    Name="WorkOrderName" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ItemNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RoomName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="WorkOrderName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Height" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Width" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Depth" Type="Double" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="ReleaseDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="ProductionStartDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="StageDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="ShipDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="DeliveryDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="InstallDate" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`?

Comment: Is the search box on the same page?

Comment: Changing AutoGenerateColumns to True resulted in the same blank page.

Comment: The search box is on a different page. The search works, shows the expected results, but when trying to edit the results in the grid the page goes blank.

Comment: Ah, i was thinking control parameter, not form parameter.

Comment: I could be wrong but i think you have to work with a dataset for updates, etc.

Comment: I’m not sure where I’m stuck. I have a page that queries a SQL table not bound by an input parameter, it just returns all data in the table. On that grid, I can edit without issue. The code, in comparison, is almost exactly the same with the exception of a WHERE clause.